# bulk database insert with id

Tags: php, mysql

I have hundred of thousands of elements to insert into a database. I realized calling an insert statement per element is way too costly and I need to reduce the overhead.
I recon each insert can have multiple data elements specified such as

```
INSERT INTO example (Parent, DataNameID) VALUES (1,1), (1,2)
```

My issue is that since the "DataName" keeps repeating itself for each element I thought it would optimize space if I stored these string names in another table and reference it.
However that causes problems for my idea of the bulk insert which now requires a way to actually evaluate the ID from the name before calling the bulk insert.

Any recommendations?
Should I simply de-normalize and insert the data every time as plain string to the table?
Also what is the limit of the size of the string as the string query amounts to almost 1.2 MB?

I am using PHP with MySQL backend

Comment: Why is calling an insert per element too costly if you're only working with thousands of elements?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: correction: hundreds of thousands, data is coming from files which are in xml format. I have a 2.5 Gigaherts machine and it takes almost 2 minutes! I don't see what to optimize but the facts pointed out above, i just have a loop with an insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us a lot of info on the database structure or size, but this may be a case where absolute normalization isn't worth the hassle.

However if you want to keep it normalized and the strings are already in your other table (let's call it `datanames`), you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO example (Parent, DataNameID) VALUES
(1, (select id from datanames where name='Foo')),
(1, (select id from datanames where name='Bar'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should insert the name in the table.
Than call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the id.

Than you can do your normal inserts.

If your table is `MYisam` based you can use `INSERT DELAYED` to improve performance: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

Comment: Note on `INSERT DELAYED`: the actual insert takes of course _longer_ in the MySQL database itself, only because the code doesn't wait on completion the script inserting it is indeed faster.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read up on [**load data (local) infile**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). It works great, I use it all the time.

**EDIT:** the answer only addresses the sluggishness of individual inserts. As @bemace points out, it says nothing about string IDs.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of finding the string IDs at all